# How to detect a network device's promiscuous mode in modern Linux?

Tags: linux, networking, ethernet

I'm wondering how to detect promiscuous mode of an interface in modern Linux
("Modern" meaning the lack of `netstat`).

I'm looking for a solution more user-friendly than checking flag `0x100` in `/sys/class/net/*/flags`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ip -d link` will show "promiscuity 1" for such devices.

Comment: I use `ifconfig ens160 -promisc` to disable promiscuous mode, and I check through `netstat -i` and the last flag did not contain `P`, but `ip -d link show ens160` will show "promiscuity 1" in the second line. why?

Comment: Because the value in `ip link` isn't really a boolean flag; it's a _counter_ (a reference count) of currently active "programs using promisc-mode". It means that besides your ifconfig parameter (the permanent setting), there is still a process running that has implicitly caused promisc mode to be enabled.

Comment: Thanks, now I see, is there any methods for finding the process running that has implicitly caused promisc mode to be enabled?